# Copying content from cell and pasting into new comments/Notes in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy content from cells of sheet1 and paste it in other Sheet2 in the form of comments/Notes through VBA. can anyone help?

[image: sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rngInput As Range
Dim rngOutput As Range
Dim cll As Range

For i = 1 To rngInput.Count
    'rngInput(i).Copy
    rngOutput(i).AddComment
    rngOutput(i).Comment.Text Text:=rngInput(i).Value2
Next
```

Comment: You don't need `rngInput(i).Copy`.

Comment: @MichalRosa, does that code copies value from the other sheet?

Comment: @AkhilG - depends how you define the ranges, it's an exercise for you to do it since you have not contributed to the solution of your own problem yet.

Comment: @MichalRosa, Thanks for your words..
I have found the solution for the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim sheetnameLR As Integer

sheetnameLR= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1  

For x = i To j
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Cells(sheetnameLR, x - 1).AddComment ThisWorkbook.Sheets("othersheet").Cells(x, i).Value

Next x
```